# Change connection strings in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, configuration, app-config

I am developing win forms and i have App config file .How can I write to connection strings section of app config file?
 My current App.Config file is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="MyDbConnection" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and my C# code to change the Connection String is

```
var Config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
                var connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)Config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
                ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConnection"].ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + "";
                Config.Save();
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

however Exception is generated at 3rd Line it is

```
configuration error exception this configuration is read only
```

The code to change connection strings is called from an external class.I dont know where should i place the code to override IsReadonly() method .
Also app config does not have code behind file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDBConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
            connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MySQLServerDB; Integrated Security=true" />
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

When you save your connection string in App.config file you can use System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager class to read this connection string in code.

```
ConnectionStringSettings  conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConnectionString"];
```

ConnectionStringsSettings class provides properties to read connection string settings in your program as follows:

```
string name = conSettings.Name;
string providerName = conSettings.ProviderName;
string connectionString = conSettings.ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 1):

To write your connection string in **App.config** file you can use:

Create two settings, example: **AppConnectionString** (type: string) and **ServerConnectionString** (type: ConnectionString)

Modify settings code, on get property of **ServerConnectionString** setting change the return value to **AppConnectionString**.

By doing this you can modify, save, or reload **AppConnectionString** setting, and when you refer to **ServerConnectionString** on your application, it will return **AppConnectionString** setting. TRY IT.